# Segre Embedding and Group Actions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, limits-colimits

The segre embedding takes two schemes $X, Y$ with $G_m$ and (I think) produces an embedding $X/G_m \times Y/G_m \hookrightarrow (X \times Y)/G_m$, with $G_m$ acting diagonally on $X \times Y$.

My confusion is that this seems like a "limit of colimit" to "colimit of limit" sort of map. Or at least, by the nature of the way things are pointing can't make use of the universal properties of these objects. I feel like the more natural thing to consider would be a map
$$
(X \times Y)/G_m \to X/G_m \times Y/G_m
$$

which naively would send $[(x, y)]$ (the equivalence class of $(x, y)$ to $([x], [y])$, which is well-defined on equivalence classes. Is this related to the Segre embedding at all? Is this even a well-defined map? Is there any reason why this latter map isn't discussed as much? Is there a group-actiony perspective on the Segre Embedding? Thanks!

Comment: this is not what most people mean when they say "Segre embedding" although perhaps it is a generalization of the usual one. Do you have a reference?

Comment: The usual segre embedding is a map $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^{nm + n + m}$, which is a map $\mathbb{A}^{n+1} - 0/G_m \times \mathbb{A}^{m+1} - 0/G_m \to \mathbb{A}^{(n+1)(m+1)} - 0/G_m$. This is not quite what I mention in the beginning, as $(\mathbb{A}^{n+1} - 0) \times (\mathbb{A}^{m+1} - 0) \neq \mathbb{A}^{(n+1)(m+1)} - 0$, but the former does include into the latter in a way that is equivariant with respect to the diagonal action on the product and the usual action on the target. @hunter

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your proposed map the other way means, since e.g. in the affine space example, (x, y) might not be zero but x might be.

Comment: Oh yeah this project is hopeless, the dimensions are all wrong. $\mathbb{A}^{n+1} \times \mathbb{A}^{m+1} = \mathbb{A}^{n+m+2}$, very different from the target of the Segre Embedding

Comment: nothing is hopeless!